# Firebase cloud function image resize

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Following the example here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js

How do I notify the client when the image is processed?

I want to have a form upload a photo and resize it to multiple sizes. How do I let the client know when the the cloud function is finished?

I'm using `firebase/storage` to upload the image client side, then I have a could function listening for files to be uploaded `functions.storage.object().onFinalize` and processing/resize the images. Is there a callback to the client when the cloud function is finished or to I need to setup pub/sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ultimate new images (the small ones - or whatever they are), would have some URL, let's say storageCompany.net/123123123123.jpg

So in your realtime Firebase, you will have some location that gives these URLs.

So maybe something like ..

```
user/NNNN/photos/thumbnails
```

so to be clear, you might have

```
user/NNNN/photos/thumbnails/726376733677.jpg
user/NNNN/photos/thumbnails/808080188180.jpg
user/NNNN/photos/thumbnails/363636636636.jpg
```

and now you're adding

```
user/NNNN/photos/thumbnails/123123123123.jpg
```

So indeed, your apps would simply watch for new items (ie, strings - the URLs) appearing in that location!

---

Just to be clear, let's say you have an ios or droid app that shows "any sort of images", and this is a Firebase project.

So, in your example is "thumbnail images" which are "created by a server".

But it just doesn't matter what sort of images you are showing.

In a

- Firebase project, which
- "Shows images"

The basic idea is simply what I explain above - you just have, one way or another, **a Firebase location which has "the URLs of the images"**

It's that simple!

Once the image is "ready" - no matter how that happens - upload, image being generated by 3D software .. whatever ..

That's how you make a Firebase project "with images".  iOS, droid or www.

Of course there are many variations.  In this example ..

[image]

We have a big folder with many "images".  each "image" has many fields, including various actual image URLs (thumbnails, big thumbnails, videos, etc etc)

Precisely as you ask, the "thumbnail" (say) URL only appears when that image has been created and upload to some storage URL!

Comment: so I should store the file paths in my cloud storage and then listen for them using https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen ?

Comment: definitely, that is exactly what you do !

Answer (score 1):

You will have to arrange for an exchange point between the client and your function.  Typically, that will be some known location in the database where the function will write the result, and the client can listen for changes to know when the work is complete.

The example you're using will need to be modified to allow the client and server to agree on a unique location ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with Firebase image resizing - (1) it's tricky to notify the client once the image resizing is complete, and (2) you never know which exact size the client-side app may need (assuming you're building a responsive app).

These two issues can be solved by using a dynamic image resizing approach. The client app can upload images directly to Google Storage (via signed URLs and PUT requests), once the upload is complete it can request the resized image(s) right away. For example:

[`https://i.kriasoft.com/sample.jpg`](https://i.kriasoft.com/sample.jpg) - original image
[`https://i.kriasoft.com/w_200,h_100/sample.jpg`](https://i.kriasoft.com/w_200,h_100/sample.jpg) - dynamically resized image

The resized images can be cached in both the Google Storage bucket and at CDN.

```
$ npm install image-resizing --save
```

```js
const { createHandler } = require("image-resizing");

module.exports.img = createHandler({
  // Where the source images are located.
  // E.g. gs://s.example.com/image.jpg
  sourceBucket: "s.example.com",

  // Where the transformed images need to be stored.
  // E.g. gs://c.example.com/w_80,h_60/image.jpg
  cacheBucket: "c.example.com",
});
```

https://github.com/kriasoft/image-resizing